# Gluon Fusion in Top Pair Production

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, gluons

In my textbook, there is a feynman diagram showing top + anti-top pair production with a highly energetic gluon resulting from the fusion of two gluons.

I know that all vector bosons have spin 1, so how is the spin quantum number conserved in this interaction?

Comment: I also have this question, I have been wondering that for quite some time. If I would guess, I would say that you either need some orbital angular momentum or this diagram can't exist by itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you mean this diagram?

[image: top antitop]

Spins are not scalar quantities and are subject to [total angular momentum conservation](http://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Services/Class/PHYS480/qm_PDF/chp6.pdf) rules. Two spin one particles can make a spin one particle, as two vectors of unit length can vectorially add up to a unit length. The top antitop come out in a spin state whose projection is such as to match the gluon spin at the vertex. This *matching*  of spins and spin projections is part of the calculation entering to evaluate the cross section for the reaction to take place. In contrast to photons, [gluons have self interaction terms.](http://bolvan.ph.utexas.edu/~vadim/classes/2013s/qcdfr.pdf)